# Cannot connect to MariaDB in Docker container from outside Docker

Tags: docker, mariadb, containers

I have the following Docker service, I am using Windows Docker Desktop:

```
database:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb_db
    hostname: mariadb_db
    ports:
      - "54327:5432"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: jwt-auth-app
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - app_net
```

This container is running correctly.

I am struggling to connect to it no matter what I try.

Here is what I've tried in HeidiSQL client:

[image]

Here is what the container looks like:

[image]

Comment: Worth checking your container logs to see if anything weird is going on. Also why not port 3306? 5432 is the Postgres default, not MySQL.

Comment: as @tadman said you have the container port rong.  Sould be 3306.  You're forwarding to a port nothing is listening on

Comment: @tadman I think you just helped me fix it! I changed ports: "54327:5432" to "3306:3306" and it connected! I copied the YAML config from an older Postgres app and forgot to change it!